How do i flash custom firmware into esp wroom 32 using openocd with esp-prog via JTAG?
I need to flash a binary using openocd on ubuntu. My commands look like this:
openocd -s ~/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts -f interface/ftdi/esp32_devkitj_v1.cfg -f board/esp-wroom-32.cfg -c "program_esp esp-at.bin 0x100000 verify exit"

Connection:



esp32
ESP-PROG




GPIO15
TDO


GPIO12
TDI


GPIO15
TCK


GPIO12
TMS



Output:
Open On-Chip Debugger v0.12.0-esp32-20230419 (2023-04-18-22:02)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 20000 kHz
WARNING: boards/esp-wroom-32.cfg is deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
** program_esp input args <0x1000 verify exit> **
Error: unable to open ftdi device with description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked
/home/szymon/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.12.0-esp32-20230419/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg:4: Error: 
at file "/home/szymon/.espressif/tools/openocd-esp32/v0.12.0-esp32-20230419/openocd-esp32/share/openocd/scripts/target/esp_common.cfg", line 4

esp-prog is detected by system.
I tried to do this using 3 esp-progs and 2 different micro usb wires. Tried to flash it using usb-uart bridge using idf.py and it works fine.

Can you share the output of lsusb, just to confirm the VID/PID for the FTDI adapter is the same as expected in the config file.  Also your adapter speed is set to 20 MHz. Try dropping this to a lower value, maybe 10000 kHz or even lower.
